# How can I recover a deleted character in GTA:V?

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-v

I deleted my account by accident. Is there any way I can recover my GTA:V character?

Answer (score 6):

It is fairly likely that you will not be able to get the account back, but if anyone is able to recover the account after it has been deleted it is Rockstar support. You can [submit a ticket with them](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).